# Ruby Hash manipulation

Tags: ruby

I am consuming an API and receiving a JSON response which I have parsed to an array of Ruby hashes.
This gives me the below.

```
[{"name"=>"Recipient", "value"=>"Joe Bloggs"},
{"name"=>"Company", "value"=>"Big Corp"}]
```

What I would like to do is convert this to the following format.

```
{"Recipient"=>"Joe Bloggs",
"Company"=>"Big Corp"}
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what exact output you desire?

Comment: Your question is unclear. The "hash" you show at the beginning of your question is not a hash. Those are *two* hashes. How are you getting those two hashes? Are there always two hashes or can there be three? Likewise, your "following format" is again two hashes. How do you want those two hashes stored? Also, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What did you try to get unstuck? You need to show your code and demonstrate your effort; [so] is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Once the JSON is parsed I have an array of hashes. I have updated the question. Sorry for not clarifying earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Here's one:

```
response = [{"name"=>"Recipient", "value"=>"Joe Bloggs"}, {"name"=>"Company", "value"=>"Big Corp"}]

response.map(&:values).to_h
  #=> {"Recipient"=>"Joe Bloggs", "Company"=>"Big Corp"}
```

Comment: Note: You seem to be a bit confused (or unaware?) of the difference between an `Array` and a `Hash`?... Your input appears to be an `Array` (of `Hash`es), but you didn't use complete syntax. And you presumably want the result to be a `Hash`, but used incorrect syntax? Anyway, this is what I assumed in my answer above.

Answer (score 4):

Let me assume all your hashes are in an array named `a`

Input

```
a = [{"name" => "Recipient", "value" => "Joe Bloggs"},
     {"name" => "Company", "value" => "Big Corp"}]
```

Code

```
p a.map { |x| [[x["name"], x["value"]]].to_h }
```

Output

```
[{"Recipient"=>"Joe Bloggs"}, {"Company"=>"Big Corp"}]
```